# Query an array variable using mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to query mongodb using mongoid in my rails app.

**Rails Version: 4.0.4 - Mongoid Version: 4.0.2**

I have a variable that returns an array ( This is querying a MySQL database )

```
@info = AdminItems.where("state LIKE '%#{params[:state]}%'").pluck(:id)
```

> this returns the results:  [1,4,6,130,190]

I am trying to return a list of documents from my MongoDB like this:

```
@admininfo = AdminInfo.where(id: @info).as_json
```

> this returns the result: []

I have attempted to do a .each do using mongoid like this:

```
@info.each do |data|
 @admininfo = AdminInfo.where(id: data).as_json
end
```

and in the console I show it querying through each of them like this:

> MOPED: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx QUERY        database=info_db
>   collection=admin_info selector={"id"=>"1"} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0
>   batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 180.8540ms
>
> through all of them (didnt want to clutter)

It appears when there is an array of more than one return, the query doesnt actually grab any documents, however if the result of @info is [1]

it will grab the document and I can call it in the view using the @admininfo.

I have done some Mongoid searching, and either can't quite find the correct syntax to do what im looking to do, or I simply can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
@admininfo = AdminInfo.where(id: @info)
```

with

```
@admininfo = AdminInfo.any_in(id: @info)
```

`any_in` is better used for checking values from an array.

Also, below code:

```
@info.each do |data|
  @admininfo = AdminInfo.where(id: data).as_json
end
```

over-writes the value of `@admininfo` in each iteration of the loop. Instead, you can check this by using `map`:

```
@admininfo = @info.map do |data|
  AdminInfo.where(id: data)
end.as_json
```